# Analyzing quantized results from a varying probability

Tags: probability

There is an event which occurs every second, and will always be in one of precisely two states (let's say "Up" and "Down"). The only data available to us is the stream of events; the goal is to ascertain, as accurately as possible, the actual probability `p` of an Up event. Wrinkle: This probablity can change over time.

So far, my best ideas are (1) an actual rolling average ("of the most recent 60 events, 54 were Up and 6 were Down, so judge that p = 0.9"), and (2) an exponentially weighted average, such that recent events influence it more than older ones do.

There is a clear tradeoff in the length of the averaging window (more accurate vs more responsive to change), and that's an easy tweakable. The question is: What actual formula/algorithm/technique should be used here, for the most useful results?

(If anyone's curious, I'm trying to analyze a flaky connection by measuring packet loss.)

Comment: Do you have a model for how the probability can change over time? Without that it doesn't seem very clear what "the actual probability" would in fact mean.

Comment: No, and in fact, that's the entire point of this analysis - to discover that. If you prefer, replace "actual probability" with some term describing it predictively - that is, the conclusion could be "I predict a 78% chance that the next event will be Up". It's the same thing looked at differently.

Comment: I'm dubious that progress can be made without -some- kind of modeling assumption. That said, I'll note that if you fail to get a helpful response here you may try [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead. That's a more specifically stats-oriented SE site. (MSE also has stats questions, but it's not so tailored to them as CV is.)

Comment: Thanks! There are a *lot* of SEs, and I appreciate the pointer!

Comment: Question reposted here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511003/analyzing-quantized-results-from-a-varying-probability

Comment: Okay. You may want to note that it's cross-posted there as well. (I'm not sure what the attitude on cross-posting is these days, but noting it explicitly seems courteous.)

Comment: Done. :thumbsup: